# How can I determine how a user has logged in user AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito and I want to check if they've logged in using Apple, Google, Facebook or normal username/password but I can't find this anywhere?

Comment: Have you checked this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/understanding-amazon-cognito-entries.html#cognito-cloudtrail-events-createidentitypool ?

Comment: I need to access this on the frontend